# C# MVC Change the Startup Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, membership-provider

I just created my first C# Razor MVC3 project. I've dabbled in it before but this is the first time I created one.

Anyhow, I have a simple question. I am using the `MembershipProvider` `AspNetSqlProfileProvider` that was build with the default project.

My question is simple, where and how do I check if the user is logged on before it loads the `Home/Index.cshtml` so that I can direct them to another page?

If they are logged on, I want to take them to the customer portal.

If they are not logged on, I want to take them to the logon screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic way to set this up would involve 2 steps:

First, add an [Authorize] attribute to your action that you are securing:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index() {

}
```

This will make sure that the user has authenticated (using FormsAuthentication).

Second, in your Web.config file, set the URL that you want the user to be redirected to when they need to login.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="cookieName" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="30" domain=".example.com" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I like this option. Forgot about that as I usually don't use built-in authentication

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options here. You could do it in your home/index view (if that's what you're calling it), and then just use something like:

```
 if(Request.IsAuthenticated())
    return RedirectToAction("login","login");
```

Or you could probably do it in the application startup method. I'd probably just do the first one, though.

Comment: This gave me a few ideas but this is after the user logs in and not before the logon screen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ErocM well by home/index I meant whatever is your default landing page. That should be before anybody logs in.

Answer (score 0):

The page (url rather) which the user is redirected to if not logged in is defined in the `Web.config` under:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/GetIn" .... />
    </authentication>
```

If logged in however the ASP.NET MVC routing kicks in, which is in `Global.asax.cs` and by default has this route:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {
            controller = "Home",
             action = "Index",
             id = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
```

Which means that if no controller or action were specified in the URL then it will default to `Home` and `Index`